# Why do I keep getting a request to install JDK on mid 2015 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, java, safari-extensions

After updating to  OS 10.13.1 I got messages to update JDK, I have gone to the website, downloaded then installed the update. I then have the website run a check to see if I have the latest update. The site says that I, indeed, have the latest. But every time I boot up the Mac I get the message to update.  I seem to recall this issue with an earlier update a couple of years back and don't remember how to resolve it.

[image]

Comment: Do you know what is trying to use `java` on your Mac? If you aren't sure what is causing these prompts to appear I'd recommend using a tool like [EtreCheck](https://etrecheck.com) to check what is trying to launch and call java on your Mac. It could be malicious. If it isn't malicious, knowing what it is could help identify which version of Java it's looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to download legacy Java that apple doesn't automatically ship anymore. That said, if you think you know which application may be what's requiring this, it may be a good idea to get rid of it if you don't need it. If you do need it, this should be the right download: https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US

Comment: If it helps, I've found that for most people having an older version of Adobe software (i.e. Creative Suite packages or individual apps like Photoshop) will trigger this requirement.